# Update to JDEDTA.js not showing in browser

Tags: jdedwards

We have instructions from Oracle asking us to update our JDEDTA.js file to fix a specific problem we are having in our installation.

However, we've found the file occurring in two places on the file system and have updated both of those files, restarted the services, cleared our cache on the client browser (and even tried a different browser), but the changes aren't being reflected.

Is this something I have to update in a specific .jar file or in some other location?

I apologize for the vagueness of the question, I'm not a CNC, but just trying to help troubleshoot.

Best regards,

Hal

Answer (score 0):

Every time we made changes to the web interface, we made the modifications under that directory
C:\e812\system\OC4J\j2ee\home\applications\webclient.ear\webclient\js

Hope it help you